# Python - play audio without saving it

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

I'm writing a chat-like app. I want to send data which I got from microphone to another app through UDP and I managed it, but I don't know how to play received audio without saving it to file. Does someone know how to play raw audio?

Thanks in advance,
Adam

Comment: Are you sure? It is said there, how to play audio from a website, not from bytes object.

Comment: @AdamPisula. Is the audio data in WAV format? And are you specifically using the `pyaudio` package to play it?

Comment: No, it's raw data in bytes. No, it doesn't matter how I'm gonna do that.